# Using 'tar' command in for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

I know it is the basic question but please do help me .I compressed and archived my server log file using tar command

```
for i in server.log.2016-07-05 server.log.2016-07-06 ; do tar -zcvf  server2.tar.gz $i; done
```

The output of the above loop is:

```
server.log.2016-07-05 
server.log.2016-07-06
```

But while listing the file using `tar -tvf server2.tar.gz` the output obtained is:

```
rw-r--r-- root/root 663643914 2016-07-06 23:59 server.log.2016-07-06
```

i.e., I archived two files but only one file was displayed which means archive doesnt have both files right?? Please help on this.

I just tested with these two files but my folder has multiple files. Since I didn't get expected output I was not proceeded with all the files in my folder. The exact loop I am going to use is:

```
Previousmonth=$(date "+%b" --date '1 month ago')

for i in $(ls -l | awk '/'$Previousmonth'/ && /server.log./ {print $NF}');do;tar -zcvf server2.tar.gz $i;done
```

I am trying to compress and archive multiple files but while listing the files using `tar -tvf` it doesn't shows all the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop here. Just list all the files you want to add as command line parameter:

```
tar -zcvf server2.tar.gz server.log.2016-07-05 server.log.2016-07-06
```

The same goes for your other example too:

```
tar -zcvf server2.tar.gz $(ls -l | awk '/'$Previousmonth'/ && /server.log./ {print $NF}')
```

Except that parsing the output of `ls -l` is awful and strongly not recommended.

But since the filenames to backup contain the month number,
a much simpler and better solution is to get the year + month number using the `date` command, and then use shell globbing:

```
prefix=$(date +%Y-%m -d 'last month')
tar -zcvf server2.tar.gz server.log.$prefix-??
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,both the commands u mentioned is working but we planned to execute it using crontab.So `find` method expect to mention the dates (2016-xx-xx)in all the months right??.so what is the solution for archiving and compress other than `ls -l`

Comment: If the log files are consistently named as in your example, then you don't need `ls` or any other command. See my updated solution using simple shell globbing.